# Subreport trouble in iReport 0.4.1

Tags: java, jasper-reports, report, ireport, subreport

I am using *iReport 0.4.1* and *JasperReports 0.6.3*, and I'm facing the trouble trying to generate a *subreport*:

- I set in Java code *.jasper subreport* path, it's correct, but putting wrong path for test, no errors happen;
- In subreport, putting a field for test, again no errors happen (i.e., the *subreport* is not accessed...);
- I tried to access *subreport* list by two ways: as parameter and as a main report bean field (it's not the case: in fact I have two not-related reports to print in the same page, so that's why the *subreport*);
- In almost all tries, when didn't happen error, appears a blank where *subreport's* data had to be
- PS.: I put the *subreport* in *Detail* band, with main report data.

Could somebody help me? - both reports code below.

PS 2: I can't change versions, it's a new report in an existent structure, with this *iReport* and *JasperReports* version.

Java report calls:

```java
parameters.put("subreportPath", projetoPath + "<CAMINHO>\\" + "xxxzz.jasper"
.................
parameters.put("ListaComparativoSaldos", listaSubreport);
//ABAIXO: nao funcionou
//parameters.put("ListaComparativoSaldos", new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(listaSubreport));
.................
return JasperFillManager.fillReport(is, parameters, new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(data));
```

Comment: do you have your code surrounded with a try/catch?